# App Engine remote_api with OpenID

Tags: google-app-engine, openid

I've recently tried to switch my app engine app to using openID, but I'm having an issue authenticating with remote_api. The old authentication mechanism for remote_api doesn't seem to work (which makes sense) - I'm getting a 'urllib2.HTTPError: HTTP Error 302: Found', which I assume is appengine redirecting me to the openid login page I've set up.

I guess I'm missing something fairly obvious.  Currently my remote_api script has the following in it -

```
remote_api_stub.ConfigureRemoteDatastore(app_id=app_id, path='/remote_api', auth_func=auth_func, servername=host, secure=secure)
```

where auth_func is

```
def auth_func():
  return raw_input('Username:'), getpass.getpass('Password:')
```

Any ideas what I need to supply to remote_api? I guess similar issues would be encountered with bulkloader too. Cheers,

Colin

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This was a fun one.

Looking at remote_api, the flow for authentication seems to be something like this:

- Prompt the user for Google credentials
- Post the credentials to https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin
- Parse the `auth` token out of the response body
- Pass the token to https://myapp.appspot.com/_ah/login
- Grab `ACSID` cookie set in the response
- Pass the `ACSID` cookie in subsequent requests that require authorization

I couldn't find a lot of documentation on the new OpenID support, though [Nick's blog entry](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/05/Using-OpenID-authentication-on-App-Engine) was informative.

Here's the test app I wrote to see how things work:

app.yaml:

```
handlers:
- url: /remote_api
  script: $PYTHON_LIB/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/handler.py
  login: admin
- url: /.*
  script: test.py
```

test.py:

```
class MainPage(webapp.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    user = users.get_current_user()
    if user:
      self.response.out.write("Hi, %s!<hr>admin is %s" % (user.user_id(),
        users.is_current_user_admin()))
    else:
      self.redirect(users.create_login_url('/', None,
        'https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id'))
```

Flipping my auth mode between Google Accounts and Federated Login, I noticed a few things:

- Admin users are correctly recognized by is_current_user_admin() with OpenID
- Mixing modes doesn't work. With authentication set to Google Accounts, calling create_login_url with a federated_identity throws a NotAllowedError
- An `ACSID` cookie is still produced at the end of the login process, only it comes from /_ah/openid_verify instead of /_ah/login

So what's happening with remote_api when using Federated Login? If we're using the default appengine_rpc.HttpRpcServer, it's dutifully following the same Google Account authentication process described at the top, only the app no longer considers the `ACSID` cookie returned by /_ah/login to be valid, so since you're still unauthenticated, you get a 302 redirect to the OpenID login page, /_ah/login_required.

I dunno what the right solution is here. Seems like it would require an API update. Maybe Nick or one of the other Googlers can weigh in.

For now, here's a hacky workaround:

- Turn on Federated Login for your app
- Make sure you're passing save_cookies=True when calling remote_api_stub.ConfigureRemoteDatastore for your console script
- Attempt console authentication and get the 302 error
- Login as an admin via your app's web interface
- In your browser cookies, find the ACSID cookie for myapp.appspot.com
- Find and edit your local ~/.appcfg_cookies file
- Replace the ACSID cookie for myapp.appspot.com with the one from your browser

The next time you try to use remote_api, it should work without prompting for credentials. You'll have to repeat the last 4 steps every time the cookie expires, though. You can bump the expiration from 1 day to as high as 2 weeks in the admin console to minimize the annoyance. Have fun!

Comment: There is a hacky solution - I'll be blogging about it shortly. I don't have it put together yet, though. :/

Comment: Awesome answer - cheers Drew. Works perfectly :) For others, you need to structure your cookie according to the netscape cookie format.  Its a single line of text per cookie - a series of tokens separated by tabs. The following worked for me '<my-app>.appspot.com   FALSE   /   FALSE   <expiry (unix time format)>  <cookie string>' - section 3.5 here - http://www.cookiecentral.com/faq/ gives an example. Note I didn't put the leading '.' and had FALSE instead of TRUE compared to the example.  Also the actual ACSID cookie string is much longer. Thanks again.

Comment: Nice answer. you can also switch back to Google accounts, if you are not using OpenId functionality, like me. :)

Answer (score 3):

This is definitely an issue... mark your interest in getting Google to fix this by starring the ticket at http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=3258 and feel free to add any of your workarounds there.

On a related note, we also recognize that the docs are somewhat sparse, so I'm working on an article which hopefully fills-in some of those holes... stay tuned and keep your eyes open at http://code.google.com/appengine/articles

Answer (score 2):

Here's [a workaround you can use](http://blog.notdot.net/2010/06/Using-remote-api-with-OpenID-authentication) until there's a more permanent solution in place.

Comment: @Nick This seems to be python specific. Has a permanent solution come up, and is there one for Java?