# Secure remote_api in app engine with OpenID

Tags: google-app-engine, openid

I previously asked a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2981226/app-engine-remote-api-with-openid) about using app engine's remote_api with openID, and the answer worked well, both securely and insecurely.  At some point soon after, however, something in app engine changed, and the solution no longer worked securely - i.e. the following

```
remote_api_stub.ConfigureRemoteDatastore(app_id=app_id, path='/remote_api', auth_func=auth_func, servername=host, secure=True)
```

stopped working (always returning 302), and I needed to remove the secure argument to get it to work.

The [release of the 1.3.5 SDK](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine/browse_thread/thread/6a481b951118b4f2/e4b290f4811fb125#e4b290f4811fb125) promised 'Remote API commands can be sent over HTTPS or HTTP', which confused me, as I was under the impression that providing the 'secure=True' argument had been giving me this already, based on [this discussion](http://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine/browse_thread/thread/cec8a895d08335b4/9f474dc0848a4ca8?q=#9f474dc0848a4ca8).

My suspicion is that it was the release of this feature that caused the 'secure' argument to stop working.  So the first part of my question - was I actually running remote_api commands securely by using the 'secure=True' argument, prior to the release of 1.3.5?

Once the cookie hack stopped working securely, I tried out Nick Johnson's solution listed in the same question, but with this also, I could not supply 'secure=True', getting the same 302 response.

What do I need to do to run remote_api securely with openID? Does 1.3.5 include new capabilities around this, and how do I use them?  Cheers,

Colin

Comment: Are you using my hack or Nick's less hacky hack? [ http://blog.notdot.net/2010/06/Using-remote-api-with-OpenID-authentication ]

Comment: I've tried both - I get the same behaviour - setting 'secure=True' always results in a 302 - removing 'secure=True' everything works fine.  I've got 'secure: optional' in app.yaml on the remote_api entry point. I was originally using your hack successfully with secure=True, then one day (around the 1.3.5 pre-release announcement) 302 started being returned.  At this point I tried Nick's less hacky hack, but it too only worked without 'secure=True'. I'm pretty sure it wasn't a problem with the cookie, because the same cookie worked fine if 'secure=True' wasn't present.

Comment: secure openid is not yet work on google app engine. http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=3586

Comment: @iamgopal This was working prior to 1.3.5 - but possible the issues are the same. Ta.

Comment: Note that the fixing of this issue - http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=3393 - in 1.3.8 does not help with the remote_api problem reported here

Comment: Unless of course I've tested it too early :)

Answer (score 1):

Regards this

http://code.google.com/intl/en-US/appengine/articles/openid.html

> WARNING: at the time of this writing, OpenID is not supported if your app runs in secure mode using HTTPS.

Regards [this](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/source/browse/trunk/python/google/appengine/ext/remote_api/remote_api_stub.py?spec=svn61&r=61) in last revision in 1.3.7 release

```
def ConfigureRemoteDatastore(app_id,
                             path,
                             auth_func,
                             servername=None,
                             rpc_server_factory=appengine_rpc.HttpRpcServer,
                             rtok=None,
                             secure=False):
  """Does necessary setup to allow easy remote access to an AppEngine datastore.

  Either servername must be provided or app_id must not be None.  If app_id
  is None and a servername is provided, this function will send a request
  to the server to retrieve the app_id.

  Args:
    app_id: The app_id of your app, as declared in app.yaml.
    path: The path to the remote_api handler for your app
      (for example, '/remote_api').
    auth_func: A function that takes no arguments and returns a
      (username, password) tuple. This will be called if your application
      requires authentication to access the remote_api handler (it should!)
      and you do not already have a valid auth cookie.
    servername: The hostname your app is deployed on. Defaults to
      <app_id>.appspot.com.
    rpc_server_factory: A factory to construct the rpc server for the datastore.
    rtok: The validation token to sent with app_id lookups. If None, a random
      token is used.
    secure: Use SSL when communicating with the server.
```

So, did you try it with new sdk?

Comment: @eugene this is the same information as contained in the link provided by @iamgopal in the comments on Aug 21. So google deprecated this capability with 1.3.5?

Comment: i think so, maybe we should wait for 1.3.6 roadmap to check it.

Comment: @eugene 1.3.7 is out. I don't think this answer adds anything that wasn't already present in the question/comments.

Comment: @eugene this documentation is the same as in previous versions, and no, it doesn't work. That is the question - why has this argument stopped working - it did work as documented, with openID until ~1.3.5