# Google App Engine - Federated ID (OpenID) cannot run in SSL

Tags: google-app-engine, openid

The documentation for Google App Engine Federated IDs [states](https://developers.google.com/appengine/articles/openid#su):

> WARNING: at the time of this writing, OpenID is not supported if your app runs in secure mode using HTTPS.

I am just checking to see if this is still the case. The bug seems to be related to [Issue 3586](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=3586), which remains unresolved.

There is a similar question, but it has not been updated in two years: [Secure remote_api in app engine with OpenID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3226880).

If I understand correctly, this issues means that one cannot use OpenIDs with Google App Engine if your app requires SSL. Do I understand correctly? Are there any workarounds (e.g. [Janrain's RPX](https://rpxnow.com/))?

Comment: Hmm, I tried it on my app engine site and it seems to work.

Comment: Clarification: it works on https://mysite.appspot.com (not a real address). AFAIK it does not work on custom domains with SSL.

Comment: @PeterKnego: Thanks Peter, that's interesting. The SSL on custom domains is [another issue altogether](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=792). :)